# Building error gcc-5.1.0 on ubuntu:

Tags: ubuntu, gcc

Got the following error during the building of gcc-5.1.0 on ubuntu:

> checking for int64_t underlying type... long long
>   configure: error: error verifying int64_t uses long long

The configuration was:

> CONFIGURE = ../../gcc-5.1.0/configure
>
> OPT = --program-suffix=-5.1.0                       \
>         --prefix=/opt/gcc-5.1.0                       \
>         --with-local-prefix=/opt/gcc-5.1.0            \
>         --enable-languages=c,c++                      \
>         --enable-threads=posix                        \
>         --enable-__cxa_atexit                         \
>         --enable-c99                                  \
>         --enable-long-long                            \
>         --disable-shared                              \
>         --disable-multilib                            \
>
> all:  $(CONFIGURE) $(OPT)

Can anybody clarify how to fix it?

Comment: It looks like you might be trying to build a 64-bit version on a 32-bit machine. Check the architecture of the `gcc` you're building and the machine you're building it on.

Comment: no i am trying to build 64-bit version on 64-bit ubuntu

Comment: Try to install GCC 5.1 for Ubuntu. Or at least run `aptitude build-dep gcc` to get all the required dependencies needed to build the system's GCC compiler. They are quite similar to the dependencies needed by your GCC 5.1

Answer (score 9):

Googling the error message comes up with [this bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63509) as the first result that surmises that the error message is caused by trying to build `gcc` without a C++ compiler.

To solve this, install a C++ compiler first. On Ubuntu you could try G++:

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok. The problem was the following:

the command g++ was not avaliable.

Fixed by additional installation.

Answer (score 0):

As an additional hint, you might want to check whether the symlink g++ -> g++-x.y is in /usr/bin. After purging gcc 4.6 and installing (apt-get) 4.8, the link was missing on my Raspbian. If g++-x.y is in /usr/bin, there's no need to reinstall the package.

Regards